# How to create `RxAction` to enable/disable button if text in `UITextField` is valid?

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I have multiple textFields the criteria for their validation is very straight forward.

For sake of simplifying problem statement, lets assume the criteria are

> First name should have at least one character,
>     Last name should have at least one character 
>     and  Age should be greater than 0

Assume I have a validator action as

```
   validatorAction = Action<Void,Bool> {
        return Single<Bool>.create(subscribe: { (single) -> Disposable in
            if self.firstName.text?.count ?? 0 > 0 && self.lastName.text?.count ?? 0 > 0 && self.age.text?.count ?? 0 > 0 {
                single(.success(true))
            }
            else {
                single(.success(false))
            }
            return Disposables.create()
        })
   }
```

I want this action to be executed every time character in any of the textfield changes, so I bind this action to `UIControlEvents.editingChanged`

```
    self.firstName.rx.bind(to: validatorAction, controlEvent: self.firstName.rx.controlEvent(UIControlEvents.editingChanged)){ (textField) -> Void in
        return Void()
    }

    self.lastName.rx.bind(to: validatorAction, controlEvent: self.lastName.rx.controlEvent(UIControlEvents.editingChanged)){ (textField) -> Void in
        return Void()
    }

    self.age.rx.bind(to: validatorAction, controlEvent: self.age.rx.controlEvent(UIControlEvents.editingChanged)) { (textField) -> Void in
        return Void()
    }
```

Finally, I want the action to control the enable and disable state of my button

```
        validatorAction.elements
        .asObservable()
        .startWith(false)
        .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: false)
        .drive(self.submitButton.rx.isEnabled)
        .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
```

Unfortunately though code works absolutely fine, every time the `validatorAction` is executed, textField looses its focus. That causes a huge user experience problem.

I raised a [issue](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/Action/issues/143) to RxAction repo and got the response

> Hi there! It sounds like you're slightly misusing the closure that's
>   passed into the Action initializer. You'll want to try using the full
>   initializer Action(enabledIf:, workFactory:) to separate out one
>   closure to enable/disable the action, and another closure to return an
>   observable of whatever work you want done. You can then bind the
>   action to the button and it will handle enabling/disabling it for you.
>   Check out the readme for more information and let us know how it goes.

But did not get much out of it about how to use it. Can somebody show concrete code with how to use Actions to achieve the intended behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion a better approach would be to do bind Variables with textfields and do validation on Variables.

```
var firstName = Variable<String>("")
var lastName = Variable<String>("")
var age = Variable<String>("")

tfFirstName.rx.text.orEmpty.bind(to: firstName).disposed(by: rx_disposeBag)
tfLastName.rx.text.orEmpty.bind(to: lastName).disposed(by: rx_disposeBag)
tfAge.rx.text.orEmpty.bind(to: age).disposed(by: rx_disposeBag)
```

Then you can do validation like this:

```
var isValid : Observable<Bool>{
    return Observable.combineLatest( firstName.asObservable(), lastName.asObservable(), age.asObservable()){ (fname, lname, userAge) in
        return fname.count > 0 && lname.count > 0 && userAge.count > 0
    }
}
```

Finally, you can bind Action submitButton like this:

```
submitButton.rx.action = Action(enabledIf: isValid, workFactory:{input in
    //Action code here
})
```

I hope that answers your question.